# How to display the rows (<tr>) of a table on a single line(Internet Explorer 6,7)?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, css-tables, tablerow

I want to display the rows of a table on a single line. This is a problem in Internet Explorer 6 and 7 because setting the float attribute to left and the display to block won't do. And changing `<tr>`s to  `<td>`s won't do either as these html elements are generated by a framework's code that i am not allowed to change.

**Edit:** Some of you wanted the code, i dunno why it would help but here it is (specific images and classes have been edited out, the code is not available online, *some-class* may not be the same class everywhere)

```
    <table class="some-class" width="100%" border="0"
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr class="some-class">
    <td class="some-class">
      <a href="#"><img src=pic.jpg"/></a>
      <div class="some-class">
        <div class="some-class">
          <a href="#"><img src=pic.jpg"/></a>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
        </div> <a href="#"><img src=pic.jpg"/></a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr class="some-class">
    <td class="some-class">
      <a href="#"><img src=pic.jpg"/></a>
      <div class="some-class">
        <div class="some-class">
          <a href="#"><img src=pic.jpg"/></a>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
        </div> <a href="#"><img src=pic.jpg"/></a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr class="some-class">
    <td class="some-class">
      <a href="#"><img src=pic.jpg"/></a>
      <div class="some-class">
        <div class="some-class">
          <a href="#"><img src=pic.jpg"/></a>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
        </div> <a href="#"><img src=pic.jpg"/></a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: We aren't psychics so please be less vague and link to the actual code.

Comment: could you post a portion of the generated html?

Comment: If it's generated by a framework that you're not allowed to change, then you're not going to be able to do this.  Ditch the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I'm afraid I don't think this can be done in a sane and valid manner. `float: left` in a table is absolutely taboo.</strike> **Edit:** This seems to be valid (!) and possible by taking away each element's `table-*` display property, but isn't well supported by IE.

The only workable solution I can think of is manipulating the table elements using JavaScript/jQuery, and making the needed conversions (`tr`s into `td`s...).

The obvious downside of that is that it won't work with JavaScript turned off.

Comment: Why would this be a taboo? If you give the other table elements a suitable (non-`table*`) `display` value, then this should be no problem with standards compliant browsers. Example: `table, tbody {display: block} tr {float:left} td {display: inline}`

Comment: i'm not looking for a solution that has to be valided against w3c's validators, just one that looks good in all browsers, preferably without javascript

Comment: @altvali: I was just remarking to Pekka's answer. It's completely fine what you are doing, IE just doesn't support it. If you want to display the "table rows" beside each other in IE, you'll can't use tables. IE can display tables only as tables and nothing else.

Comment: @altvali @RoToRa you have a point. There are specific rules regarding `table` elements but they all vanish if you take away the `display: table-x` properties. This might actually work and be valid (in browsers other than IE), I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about reformatting on the client using Javascript and/or a Javascript library like JQuery? It should be possible to manipulate the DOM to create an appropriate display structure possibly replacing the table elements with DIVs, for example.

Comment: i'd like to find a css solution, but if it turns out that none exists, i'll try javascript. if you have any specific solutions in mind please post them as i'm not sure what approach should i use in a javascript/jQuery solution (give them position absolute and specific positions? or transforming the entire table so that trs become tds in a single tr?)

Comment: Without being able to see the start state and the target state it's next to impossible to give you anything more than hints. I'd look to remove some tags and replace others to achieve your target layout. I certainly wouldn't start looking at absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a css solution that is not without it's drawbacks, so I cannot say I whole-heartedly recommend it (and has not been thoroughly tested cross browser), but for purposes of "possibility" I offer it:

A slight modification of your html for illustration (added some classes to the `tr` tags):

```
<table class="some-class" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr class="some-class r1">
    <td class="some-class">
      <a href="#"><img src="pic.jpg"/></a>
      <div class="some-class">
        <div class="some-class">
          <a href="#"><img src="pic.jpg"/></a>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
        </div> 
        <a href="#"><img src="pic.jpg"/></a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="some-class r2">
    <td class="some-class">
      <a href="#"><img src="pic.jpg"/></a>
      <div class="some-class">
        <div class="some-class">
          <a href="#"><img src="pic.jpg"/></a>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <a href="#"><img src="pic.jpg"/></a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="some-class r3">
    <td class="some-class">
      <a href="#"><img src="pic.jpg"/></a>
      <div class="some-class">
        <div class="some-class">
          <a href="#"><img src="pic.jpg"/></a>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      <a href="#"><img src="pic.jpg"/></a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Some things to *note* before looking at the css:

1. I added `display: block` to some of the table elements for display purposes in FireFox, IE6-7 will ignore those. You may want to just target this solution to IE6-7 if you decide that it fits your purposes.
2. Some of this styling was illustration purposes.
3. This illustration uses a *set* and *equal* width to the `td` elements and is only valid for 3 rows. Numbers would have to change based on # of rows to display in line. Basically, my point is, this may not work for your situation, but it at least illustrative that given the right circumstances, it is possible to do what you requested with css only.

The css:

```
html, body {width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
table {position: relative; table-layout: fixed; width: 33%; display: block;}
tr {position: absolute; width: 100%;}
td { border: 1px solid red; width: 100%; display: block;}
tr.r1 {left: 0;}
tr.r2 {left: 100%;}
tr.r3 {left: 200%;}
```

This would ideally have rows with set heights, as the `table` ends up with a `height: 0` since the data within it is `position: absolute`, so setting a `height` to the `table` would be recommended if possible.